# How do i share a h2 database between two application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I have been trying to do this for a while , I have an admin app and main app
so the only communication between them is       Back to book list

```
            <img class="image-responsive shelf-book" th:src="#{adminPath}+@{/image/book/}+${book.id}+'.png'" width="100px" />
```

so the admin-path here is the URL of the admin but since they don't share the same database I cant view the books in my main app

I was thinking spring cloud server but didn't work , any suggestions please ?

when I added this

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test:MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

I got this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "autoServerMode && inMemory" [50100-196]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 63 common frames omitted
I added this below to both application and one app is running but the show this error
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE 
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=




 Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-196]
```

And I have already deleted the scripts from one app any suggestions as to why its saying database in use I want them to share the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the configuration file of both apps, you should indicate:

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`

where `test` is your database name.

If you use Hibernate, also don't forget to have:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

Comment: auto server - true shows and error , and another question I am using scripts

Comment: You are getting an error because you have `mem` in your url which means `in memory`. As the error says: `Feature not supported: "autoServerMode && inMemory"`.
I would suggest you to have DDL scripts in one application only.

Comment: yeah I did that now and it gives a new error saying database already in use